# Why HSQLDialect initialization takes so long in a spring boot project?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I wrote a spring boot REST api that connects to a legacy MySQL database with a huge number of tables - 10759. When I start the spring boot project the log stops at a line which indicates that HSQLDialect is initializing. It takes several minutes for the log to resume its work.

[image]

Notice the timestamps of log messages to see what I mean. Once again only the logs which indicate the issue:

```
2020-04-21 19:10:26.489  INFO 10019 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2020-04-21 19:10:26.699  INFO 10019 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
2020-04-21 19:13:06.068  INFO 10019 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

The legacy DB version:

```
innodb_version: 5.6.14
protocol_version: 10
version: 5.6.14-1+debphp.org~precise+1
version_comment: (Ubuntu)
version_compile_machine: x86_64
version_compile_os: debian-linux-gnu
```

Spring framework version

```
2.2.4
```

I also tried to force Hibernate to user `MySQL5Dialect`, by adding the following line to project's `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

But it keeps switching to HSQLDialect.

I suspect that the big count of tables somehow relates to the issue. I have similar issues while tring to connect to that same database with several MySQL GUI tools like PHPMyAdmin, DBeaver, MySQL Workbench. Some tools fail load the list of tables. Other do load them but in several minutes.

Can you explain why does it take so long to initialize the HSQLDialect and what can I do to fix that problem, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line in my `application.properties` file was causing the slow initialization:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

So I changed it to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Because of the large size of the tables I use in the database, like several thousands, Hibernate has had to check the validity of each entity's declaration against the database's table info. Since I had changed this value, the initialization time dropped to less than a second, because Hibernate already skips the validation part.